# Linux GCC not displaying string

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


int main(){
char string[]="hello";
char *str;
int size,i;
size=strlen(string);

str=(char*)malloc(size+1);

for(i=0;i<size;i++){
    str[size-i]=string[i];//Reversing the string
}
str[size+1]='\0';
printf("The reversed string is %s\n",str);//Displaying the reversed string


}
```

Above code run fine in windows machine with gcc compiler but does not work in linux gcc. Can someone explain why? But when I am prinitng the str by character by character then it shows the output but not as a string.

Comment: Besides you writing the terminator out of bounds of your allocated memory, what is the problem you're having? What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: When I run the program i just get the printf statement but reversed string i.e str is not printing out.

Comment: Then you should [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). If you do you should be able to find out the problem within a few minutes by stepping through the code line by line in a debugger.

Comment: Stack Overflow has got *tens of questions* if not *hundreds* about reversing a string in C. It might be worthwhile looking at those yourself and figuring out where you went wrong.

Comment: Also, it doesn't work on windows either.

Comment: In passing, I recommend that you read and understand [the question on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in C](/q/605845).

Answer (score 1):

Because you have `'\0'` inside `str[0]`. And it is treated as empty string.

You can easily check what is happening there using gdb:

```
> gdb file
...
...
(gdb) list
1   #include <stdio.h>
2   #include<stdlib.h>
3   #include<string.h>
4
5
6   int main(){
7     char string[]="hello";
8     char *str;
9     int size,i;
10    size=strlen(string);
(gdb) list
11
12    str=(char*)malloc(size+1);
13
14    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
15          str[size-i]=string[i];//Reversing the string
16    }
17    str[size+1]='\0';
18    printf("%d\n",str[0]);
19    printf("The reversed string is %s\n",str);//Displaying the reversed string
20
(gdb) break 17
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40063a: file file.c, line 17.
(gdb) run
...
...
Breakpoint 1, main () at file.c:17
17    str[size+1]='\0';
...
...
(gdb) print str
$1 = 0x602010 ""
(gdb) print str[0]
$2 = 0 '\000'
```

Inside your loop, you skip putting value inside `str[0]`. So, it may happen that region that you have allocated will have `str[0]` filled with `null` and your string will be treated as empty.

Comment: null character is not in str[0] its in str[size+1] i.e str[6].

Comment: The problem isn't that the OP writes the terminator to `str[0]`, but rather that `str[0]` is *uninitialized*.

Comment: And an additional problem is this out-of-bounds write : `str[size+1]='\0';`

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you are copying wrongly. Remember that indices of letters in a C-string `s` are from 0 to `strlen(s)-1` (all included) and that you have ASCII NUL at `strlen(s)`.
But your loop:

```
for (i=0;i<size;i++){
   str[size-i]=string[i];
```

fills indices from `strlen(string)` to 1 (size-(size-1)), thus `str[0]` is left uninitialized. Then trying to print `str` leads to **Undefined Behavior**, on many environement, `str[0]` will be 0 and then make `str` correspond to the empty string, but this is not guaranteed.

Solution can be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
  char string[]="hello";
  char *str;
  int size,i;

  size=strlen(string);
  str=(char*)malloc(size+1);
  for(i=0;i<size;i++){
    str[size-1-i] = string[i]; // Copying in reverse
  }
  str[size]='\0'; // end of string
  printf("The reversed string is %s\n",str); // Displaying the reversed string
}
```

Note:  you are not reversing the string, you are just building another string that is the reverse of the given one.